# Can I receive an acknowledgement when a packet that I send leaves my NIC?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, nic

My goal is to send the same message continuously (if possible to retransmit immediately after the previous transmission is completed) using a UDP protocol until I receive an acknowledgement from the receiver so that I stop transmitting the same message.

However, before retransmitting I would like to know if my previous message has left my NIC succesfully (I do not need to know if it has arrived succesfully to the receiver) so that I am sure that I do not retransmit while the previous message is waiting at the NIC buffer. Is there a way to receive a type of acknowledegement from my NIC when my packet leaves the NIC?

Comment: In a word, no. If you think you may have this problem clearly your timeout period is too short.

Comment: Isn't it possible to monitor the packets sent from an interface using the netstat -i command?

Comment: Probably, but that's a heavyweight solution to a lightweight and possibly non-existent problem. It seems to me that all you need to do is choose an appropriate retransmit interval. A second or two comes to mind. I would forget about this NIC business altogether.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I am designing a robust (robustness is very critical) application that will monitor and control a system with control messages transmitted every 50ms. And generally depending on the available resources, the control messages should be transmitted as frequently as possible.